# How to get list of ledgers from tally using XML request filtered by name that contains a specified sub-text?

Tags: xml, string, request, comparison, tally

I have the following XML request that returns the list of all ledgers from Tally.

```
<ENVELOPE>
            <HEADER>
                <VERSION>1</VERSION>
                <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
                <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
                <ID>Ledgers</ID>
            </HEADER>
            <BODY>
                <DESC>
                    <STATICVARIABLES>
                        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                    </STATICVARIABLES>
                    <TDL>
                        <TDLMESSAGE>
                            <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Ledgers">
                                <TYPE>Ledger</TYPE>                             
                                <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                                <NATIVEMETHOD>Name</NATIVEMETHOD>
                            </COLLECTION>
                        </TDLMESSAGE>
                    </TDL>
                </DESC>
            </BODY>             
        </ENVELOPE>
```

Now in the above code, I added a filter as follows:

```
<TDLMESSAGE>
     <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Ledgers">
            <TYPE>Ledger</TYPE>                             
            <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
            <NATIVEMETHOD>Name</NATIVEMETHOD>
            <FILTERS>Site</FILTERS>
      </COLLECTION>
    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Site">$Name = 'Site'</SYSTEM>
</TDLMESSAGE>
```

So, what it does is it checks if there is a ledger called 'Site'
This filter works perfectly. It only gives me one ledger whose name is 'Site'. But, what I need is a list of all the ledgers that contain the word 'Site' anywhere in their name.
Thus, I tried to use **LIKE** operator instead of **=**.

```
<SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Site">$Name LIKE 'Site'</SYSTEM>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Like** is for pattern matching and it requires **expression**.

if you want to search with string use **Contains**

```
<SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Site">$Name Contains 'Site'</SYSTEM>
```

[image]

Comment: I was actually looking for documentation on string operators on Tally XML requests.

Comment: https://help.tallysolutions.com/developer-reference/tally-definition-language/what-are-data-types-operators-and-expressions-in-tdl/#string-operators

Answer (score 0):

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
        <ID>Ledgers</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Ledgers">
                        <TYPE>Ledger</TYPE>                         
                        <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>Name</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <FILTERS>Site</FILTERS>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Site">$Name LIKE '%Site%'</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>             
</ENVELOPE>
```

This did the trick.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?